# WinError 17, WinError 12, and others when trying to rename files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to rename an X amount of JPG files that are in a folder with no success. The most frequent error I get is Winerror 12 and Winerror 17.

The .py file is inside the folder I want to modify the files of.

```
import shutil, os, re
from pathlib import Path
    
p = Path('d:\\CCACO\\CCA TEMPLATE\\C001066 Sugar Creek\\Photos FGA')
  
x = list(p.glob('*.?p?'))
y = enumerate(x, start=1)
    
for oldFileName in x:
   newFileName = 'NEW NAME'
   os.rename(oldFileName, newFileName)
   print(x)
```

```
Error: line 26, in <module>
os.rename(oldFileName, newFileName)
OSError: [WinError 17] The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive
```

I keep getting this error or variants and I do not know why if I am not trying to move anything.

Comment: Move `print(x)` as the 1st line of the loop and paste the output, to know which file triggers the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error is raised because you rename several files in the same way as said in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename). You could add the enumerator to the new name like so:

```
newFileName = 'NEW NAME'+str(y)
```

Comment: Added it with a counter for y+=1 and it did work.